# Error in plotting raster extracted from an RData file in R

Tags: raster, r

I am attempting to plot specific layers from a set of time-series rasters contained in RData format. I used the code below:

```
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(spdplyr)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

loadset <- load("MOD13Q1_MYD13Q1_EVI_97_2008_89_2009_RData.RData")
getset <- get(loadset) #successfully extracted the contents of RData file
set <- raster::stack(getset)
```

However when I start to plot or check the histogram using this code:

```
r1 <- raster(set, layer=1)
```

I get an error:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) :

What does this error mean and what's the workaround?

RData files can be found [HERE](https://github.com/mpmarcaida/RData-Files).

Comment: You need to require the associated libraries. They ate not added back when the session is opened.

Comment: Hi @JeffreyEvans, I have these libraries:library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(spdplyr)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the object

```
r1
```

or check if it has an associated filename:

```
filename(r1)
```

The `source` points to a filepath on someone's computer, and what happened was they created a raster object linked to a file i.e.

```
s <- stack("MOD13Q1_EVI_2008_097.tif")
```

and then saved it out

```
save(s, "myfile.RData")
```

All that did was save a summary of the object, like the print above - but none of the actual data from the .tif file.

This is an unfortunate side-effect of the very nice behaviour raster has of not loading any data until it is really needed.

They needed to do this before saving to .RData

```
s <- readAll(s)
```

But, .RData is a bad file format for this, better to use `writeRaster(s, filename = "somefile")` and choose a given format (like GeoTIFF, or even raster's own .gri/.grd).